# pass mysql search results url variables into 2nd php processor to download preferred files in a zip file

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic-arrays

#### SITREP

In the middle of building a cart-like document builder/downloader in PHP 5.6.11 and MySqli 5.6.30 on Ubuntu 15.04. A lot of parts work individually but not together.

A database table contains the specific names of products along with corresponding documentation urls (where the PDF's are stored on the server).

Here's the sequence of events, dictated by the end-user's workflow:

1. Set session cookie. (TBD probably hidden iframe). PHP Page #1.
2. User searches via form, submits, echos dozens of results + matching url's from the database with checkboxes. PHP Page #1.
3. User checks a few boxes for items they want to download. PHP Page #1 .
4. User searches more, check some more items. PHP Page #1.
5. User hits download button. PHP Page #1.
6. PHP Page #2 uses the `$results['url']` variables from PHP Page #1 in an array, creates a zip, adds files that were checked and prompts download.

#### I need a solution to pass the returned urls variables `$results['url']` from the database search results on PHP #1 into the PHP#2 download processor array.

PHP page #1, query is:

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mobilesearchspec
WHERE (`url` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`product` LIKE '%".$query."%') ORDER BY product ") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following

while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){

echo "<p><input type=checkbox name=item[] value=$results[url]>" ; echo "".$results['product']."<br>";
echo "<a href='" .$results['url'] . "'>". $results['url'] . "</a>";
```

Here's the full code of PHP Page #2 processor (from RajdeepPaul's solution below + wiping the zip directory):

```
$files = $_POST['item'];

$timestamp = date("M-d-Y_H:i:s"); //$timestamp takes the current time
$zipname = "zip_".$timestamp.".zip"; // add timestamp to the file name
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file){
    $downloaded_file = file_get_contents($file);
    $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$downloaded_file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile("$zipname");

// removes zip file from directory after creation
array_map('unlink', glob("*.pdf"));
array_map('unlink', glob("*.zip"));
```

**I am open to and extremely grateful for any suggestions!**

Comment: Take the `<form>` element outside of the while loop, so that you could access all the checked urls using `$_POST['item']` array on *page #2*. Besides, where's this *download* button?

Comment: The search input field, the clear form button, submit for search are in html outside of the PHP. The download button specifically is in its own form like: 
`<form action="download2.php" method="POST"><p><br><input type="submit" value="Download Selected Files" /><br><br></p> ...`

Comment: In addition to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38110368/pass-mysql-search-results-url-variables-into-2nd-php-processor-urls-arrray-to-d?noredirect=1#comment63654650_38110368), have you tried this on *Page #2*, `$files = $_POST['item'];`, this will give you an array of URLs. Plus, post the full, yet relevant, code of *Page #1*.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul adding `$files = $_POST['item'];` to _Page#2_ triggers the zip file, but its only 43 bytes in size and cannot be opened = its empty. Am I correct to assume the checkbox form isn't passing the url from _Page#1_?

Comment: That's a *may be*. To debug the issue, do `var_dump($_POST['item']);` on *Page #2* and see what you're getting.

Comment: First of all, comment out all the lines of *Page #2* except this statement, `$files = $_POST['item'];`, then do `var_dump($files);` to see the complete array of URLs. This will help you debug the issue further.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul the dump gave me:

`array(1) { [0]=> string(69) "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/images/cimages/test.pdf" } `

That is the correct path to the pdf in the table and matches the location of the file in the folder. I tried with several checkboxes, all return correct urls.

Comment: I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `foreach` loop in the following way,

```
foreach ($files as $file){
    $downloaded_file = file_get_contents($file);
    $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$downloaded_file);
}
```

So your code on *Page #2* should be like this:

```
$files = $_POST['item'];

$timestamp = date("M-d-Y_H:i:s"); //$timestamp takes the current time
$zipname = "zip_".$timestamp.".zip"; // add timestamp to the file name
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file){
    $downloaded_file = file_get_contents($file);
    $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$downloaded_file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile("$zipname");
```